# How add variable npm run build in package.json

Tags: variables, npm, package.json

I have 6 projects in an Angular workspace and I have to build each. Instead of write six lines in my package.json for each projet, for example : 
"build_a":" npm run build a" 
"buiild_b": "npm run build b"

I would like to create only one line like this :

"build_app": "npm run build name="aaa""

How I can do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution using a node.js script: build-subproject.js.

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
const args = process.argv.slice(2).join(' ');

console.log(`RUNNING build with args: ${args}`);
exec(
  `ng build ${args} && cd dist/${args} && npm pack `,
  (error, stdout) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
      return;
    }
    console.info(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  }
);
```

In package.json,

```
"build-subproject": "node ./build-subproject.js",
```

Then run , `npm run build-subproject my-project-name`

Answer (score 1):

you could rely on environment variables in order to discover such names.

however it depends on which operating system you're using on how to define env variables.

```
"scripts":{
  "build:a":"cross-env NAME=a npm run build",
  "build:b":"cross-env NAME=b npm run build",
  "build:c":"cross-env NAME=c npm run build",
  "build":"browserify src/main.js -o build.js"
}
```

You would end up with a script section more or less like this.